# Sharing enum from base class between multiple reference dlls ( Error CS0433 )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Visual Studio C#/C++ CLI.

So I have a base class and some common types in one include file.
2 different classes with some minor addons derived from it and compiled into dlls.
The main application is then referencing these 2 dlls to do some useful stuff. But each 'public enum class' defined in base file is complaining about

`Error  CS0433  The type 'XXX' exists in both ...`

when I try to use it.
I can derive unique enum names into each child class, but it looks messy and confusing especially for the functions in the base.

Are there any good practices to deal with it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is to chip out and create a 3rd dll with the common types to reference everywhere and #pragma make_public (...) all the cross native objects.